# How to log all HTTP(S) traffic between Xamarin emulator and the Internet

Tags: android, xamarin, https, xamarin.ios, web-traffic

Is there a way to log all HTTP(S) traffic between the xamarin Test Flight emulator and the Internet (browser)? We need a way to inspect all HTTP(S) traffic with incoming data so that we can see all of the "redirects" after clicking a mobile advertisement. 
For example, if you click a banner ad for a mobile app, there are typically many "redirects" before taking the user to the app store, each one being an affiliate ad network or attribution software; we need to be be able to copy and paste all of those requests. This is very important to us.

Comment: Would you be kind as to clarify what is "Xamarin Test Flight emulator" and why do you have tag android in here? It is unclear whether you want to track https requests from/to Android emulator, iOS emulator on Mac or remote iOS emulator on Windows

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tools available for this. Below are the 2 such tools which are  my favorite(I'm a Windows User):

1. Telerik Fiddler.
2. Wireshark.

As all the requests are sent through your machine only, install these tools and start recording the data. They come with awesome filters to filter out the data to the particular server too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler Everywhere, download link https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-everywhere

For Capturing Android Traffic

1. Start Fiddler Everywhere.
2. Open the Home pane.
3. Open the Remote Devices screen.
4. Open the Android tutorial and follow the instructions.

For more detail [click here](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/capture-traffic/capture-from-android)

For Capturing iOS Traffic

1. Start Fiddler Everywhere.
2. Open the Home pane.
3. Open the Remote Devices screen.
4. Open the iOS tutorial and follow the instructions.

For more detail, [click here](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/capture-traffic/capture-from-ios)

Happy Sniffing!